# transaction fee for blackberry in-app purchases?

Tags: blackberry, transactions

What is the transaction fee for blackberry in-app purchases?
Also which all countries are supported for merchant accounts for blackberry app developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [BB Developer FAQ](http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/blackberryworld/faq.html)

Section 7. Purchasing, Billing and Invoicing

*i. How is the revenue divided between a developer and BlackBerry World?*

*As of June 2011, the revenue split for applications sold via BlackBerry World is 70/30 in favour of the vendor (you).*

The same approach works for the in-app purchases.